# How to find a simple mathematical connection between a target number and a given list of numbers?

Tags: math

Say I want to create my lucky number `111` using only my day and month of birth, which are `10` and `11`. I want a simple calculation that makes use of these numbers and evaluates to `111`. In this example case one solution would be `10 * 10 + 11  = 111`.

The calculation should contain only basic mathematical operations and make use of all the given starting numbers at least once. Bonus points if it doesn't contain any other numbers, but this is not mandatory.

I tried to search around myself, but I have no idea how to explain to the search engine what it is that I want, so I endend up here. Does anybody know an online or offline tool that can do this?

Answer (score 2):

Probably want to write your own algorithm for this. 
Maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2392379/computing-target-number-from-numbers-in-a-set) is what you want?